# How to launch an application from an icon in a GridView?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a launcher, in which I've added a `GridView`. This fetches all the installed applications and arranges them in a grid.

The problem is when I click on of those grid items nothing happens, I want it to open the app.

Is it possible? Here's my code:

**Apps.java:**

```
public class Apps extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences colors_app;
    GridView mGrid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        loadApps();

        setContentView(R.layout.apps);

        mGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.app_grid);
        mGrid.setAdapter(new AppsAdapter());

        colors_app = getSharedPreferences("MyColor", 1);

        int colorcode2 = colors_app.getInt("color_code", 0);
        if (colorcode2 != 0) {

            Apps.this.findViewById(R.id.apps_back).setBackgroundColor(
                    colorcode2);

        }
    }

    private List<ResolveInfo> mApps;

    private void loadApps() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        mApps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    }

    public class AppsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        public AppsAdapter() {
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i;

            if (convertView == null) {
                i = new ImageView(Apps.this);
                i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                i.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(90, 90));
                i.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            } else {
                i = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            ResolveInfo info = mApps.get(position);
            i.setImageDrawable(info.activityInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));

            return i;
        }

        public final int getCount() {
            return mApps.size();
        }

        public final Object getItem(int position) {
            return mApps.get(position);
        }

        public final long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not have anything that is supposed to launch another app. You need to add some code to run the applications that you display in your grid. You may implement an `OnItemClickListener` for your `mGrid` or add an `OnClickListener` for each `ImageView` inside the adapter.

Check out this example from ["The Big Nerd Ranch Guide"](https://www.bignerdranch.com/books/android-programming/):

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    ResolveInfo resolveInfo = (ResolveInfo)l.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    ActivityInfo activityInfo = resolveInfo.activityInfo;
    if (activityInfo == null) return;
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.setClassName(activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, activityInfo.name);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Remember that this code is supposed to work with a `ListView` and not with a `GridView`, so make sure to implement something like this for your case. You already have a List of `ResolveInfo` objects, so you may use it to access an `ActivityInfo` of each app via the position of each item.

Comment: I added a OnItemClickListener for GridView and now it works like charm!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on my own :-) Just simply put this code in `onCreate` below `setContentView`, and you are done! Code works like charm!

```
mGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View convertView,
                    int position, long id) {
                ResolveInfo cleckedResolveInfo = (ResolveInfo) parent
                        .getItemAtPosition(position);
                ActivityInfo clickedActivityInfo = cleckedResolveInfo.activityInfo;

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                intent.setClassName(
                        clickedActivityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
                        clickedActivityInfo.name);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
```